# How to crop an image based on a complex criteria?

Tags: python, opencv, crop

I have a set of similar images like the one below. I want to keep the portion of the image that is within the top red 'irregular' rectangle (green arrows represent the space that I want to keep; anything outside I want to crop out. Is there a python opencv code that would do it for me? I've been trying to figure it out using opencv by playing around with thresholds but it's just not doing it for me.

Original image:

[image]
The area that I want to keep (the space I want to keep is highlighted by green arrows):
[image]

Desired output:
[image]

Thank you so much

Comment: Don't you mean above the first red wiggly line? Can you provide more detail about where the region of interest will be in your other images. If it is always at the top, you could flood fill it with white (and make the rest black), do some morphology and then use that as a mask with numpy to extract that region.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can see how my words may not have made sense. I want to 'keep' the area inside the top red boundaries.. so that would include the black area that I put in the desired output. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You can flood-fill the first portion of the image and then extract the blob. Additionaly, if your blob has always the greatest area of the image, you can also try flood-filling each region and looking for the largest blob.

Comment: You did not answer about whether you want to extract that very top area in all your image.

Comment: Yes... so basically I only want to keep the area below the very top red border, to the right of the left red border, to the left of the right red border, and above the first curvy red line. I want to get rid of the area below and including the middle curvy red line.

Comment: What are the constraints on the wiggly dividing line? Could it be vertical and wiggly? Could it be horizontal and wiggly and just 5 pixels down from the top? Or horizontal and wiggly and 2 pixels from the bottom? Is it always solid or could it be dashed/dotted or otherwise discontinuous?

Comment: Thank you. It is always going to be continuous and solid. It is always going to be horizontal but will have wiggles in it which may go vertically for a very tiny distance. It is almost always going to be located somewhere in the middle of the image. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it. The code that does `cv2.imwrite()` is just for debug so you can see the various stages and I have put the temporary, intermediate images in where they are produced, but you can just take all the chunks of code and append them together to make one continuous piece of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('wavy.png')
copy = im.copy()

# Flood fill with white starting from 10,10
cv2.floodFill(copy,mask=None,seedPoint=(10,10),newVal=(255,255,255))
cv2.imwrite('temp1.png',copy)
```

[image]

```
# Make everything not white into black
copy[~np.all(copy == (255, 255, 255), axis=-1)] = (0,0,0)
cv2.imwrite('temp2.png',copy)
```

[image]

```
# Make white all the bits we don't want at the bottom of the original image
im[:] |= ~copy

# Crop/trim part we want
Ynonzero, Xnonzero, _ = np.nonzero(copy)
res = im[np.min(Ynonzero):np.max(Ynonzero), np.min(Xnonzero):np.max(Xnonzero)]

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png',res)
```

[image]